# Looking to all destination generic for xcodebuild

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodebuild

In building archive for a generic device we need to use the commands like this:

```
xcodebuild -destination generic/platform=iOS ...
```

My question is about `generic/platform=iOS`, how can i find a complete list of this wording for all device's? like we got mac or tv or watch, ... I need them to use them for building my archive via terminal, I searched for first party links, but i found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

**man xcodebuild** has them:

```
macOS
iOS
iOS Simulator
watchOS
watchOS Simulator
tvOS
tvOS Simulator
visionOS
visionOS Simulator
DriverKit
```

Comment: also `visionOS` and `visionOS Simulator`

Comment: DriverKit has been added too. I'll update the list.